# Jar Within a jar Classloading and method execution

Tags: java, classloader

I have some minor issue with class loading. I have a jar say abc.jar and under that jar there is another jar called libs/cde.jar. I had written a a class in that jar that used the cde.jar. I packaged the abc.jar correct and inspected that the dependent jar was correctly packaged under /libs/cde.jar.

However, when I try load the jar (abc.jar) and execute the class which depend on cde.jar, it cannot find that dependent cde.jar. Any pointer as to how I can do it? I cannot use other jar loaders like OneJar, etc. I have to do it with pure java class loading if possible. I tried putting it in the classpath by using "file:////C:/abc.jar!/libs/cde.jar" without any success

Thanks
Masti

Answer (score 4):

Java can't, by default, deal with embedded Jars (ie Jars within Jars)

If you really want this type of behavior, you should take a look at [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)

Otherwise you will need to leave dependent Jars externally and specify there dependency via the parent Jar's `Class-Path` attribute in its `Manifest` file